Wedge product and isomorphism between $\bigwedge^{k}T_{p}^{*}M$ and $\left(\bigwedge^{k}T_{p}M\right)^{*}$
Wikipedia states that there is the following isomorphism,
$$
\bigwedge^{k}T_{p}^{*}M \cong \left(\bigwedge^{k}T_{p}M\right)^{*}
$$
More concretely, we think of the k-form, $\omega$ as either a linear map,
$$ \omega_p: \bigwedge^{k}T_{p}M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
or, alternatively,
$$ \omega_p: T^k_{p}M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
I am more familiar with the latter with the following conventions for the wedge product.
$$dx^i \wedge dx^j(u,v) = dx^i(u)dx^j(v) - dx^i(v)dx^j(u)$$
But this seems to imply that,
$$(dx^i \wedge dx^j)(u\wedge v) = (dx^i \wedge dx^j)(u\otimes v - v \otimes u) = 2\left(dx^i(u)dx^j(v) - dx^i(u)dx^j(v)\right)$$
Can someone help clarify the second expression? Do we just define it to be equal to the one above or do we get a different normalization depending how this works?

This indeed is confusing. My solution is to never take wedge products of vectors, only wedge products of differential forms. And to always view a differential $k$-form as a function of $k$ vectors or the simple tensor product of $k$-vectors and never as a function of the wedge product of vectors. There's a discussion of this here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68004/natural-pairings-between-exterior-powers-of-a-vector-space-and-its-dual.

The short answer is that once you derive $\bigwedge V^\cong(\bigwedge V)^$ and also recognize that there is a canonical way for $\bigwedge V$ to embed in the tensor algebra of $V$, you are forced to accept that the image of $(\bigwedge V)^\to\bigwedge V^$ embeds in the tensor algebra of $V^*$ in a different way.

I can elaborate on this for you (and I allude to it here) in terms of the universal properties of the exterior algebra, tensor algebra, and exterior powers. Are you comfortable with these universal properties?

I am somewhat comfortable with them although it isn't the language, I typically use when thinking about these things. I would appreciate an attempted answer in that language.

I should mention that I am not interested in the characteristic 3 case as I am mainly interested in smooth manifolds.

$
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\ExtPow[1]{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge^{\mkern-1mu#1}}}
\newcommand\Tensor{\mathop{\textstyle\bigotimes}}
\newcommand\tensor{\otimes}
\newcommand\K{\mathbb K}
\newcommand\TensorPow[1]{\mathop{\textstyle\bigotimes^{#1}}}
\newcommand\alt{\mathop{\mathrm{alt}}\nolimits}
\newcommand\Alt{\mathop{\mathrm{Alt}}}
\newcommand\lintr{\mathbin{\lrcorner}}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\tr{\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}}
\newcommand\I{\mathscr I}
$Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\K$-vector space.
The universal property of the tensor algebra $\Tensor V$
extends the map $v \mapsto v : V \to \Ext V$ into an algebra homomorphism
$\pi : \Tensor V \to \Ext V$.
The tensor algebra decomposes into tensor powers as
$$
\Tensor V = \K\oplus V\oplus\TensorPow2 V\oplus\TensorPow3 V\oplus\dotsb
$$
so use the universal properties of the tensor powers to define a linear map
$\alt_0 : \Tensor V \to \Tensor V$ by
$$
\alt_0(v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_k)
= \sum_{\sigma\in S_k}
    \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_{\sigma(k)}
$$
where $S_k$ is the set of all permutations on $k$ elements.
We discover a few things:

$\alt_0$ is almost a projection:
$\alt_0(\alt_0(X)) = k!\alt_0(X)$ for $X \in \TensorPow kV$.
This encourages us to define $\alt(X) := \frac1{k!}\alt_0(X)$
when $\K$ has the appropriate characteristic
(and henceforth we will assume characteristic 0).
This $\alt$ is a projection: $\alt\circ\alt = \alt$.
$\ker(\pi) = \ker(\alt)$ and $\pi\circ\alt = \pi$.
This means we can restrict $\pi$
to the image of $\alt$ without losing anything.
Defining $\Alt V = \alt\!\left(\Tensor V\right)$,
let $\pi'$ be the restriction of $\pi$ to this space.
The product $(X, Y) \mapsto \alt(X\tensor Y)$ on $\Alt V$ is associative
(and unital); we also have $V \subseteq \Alt V$
and $\alt(v\otimes v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$,
so by the universal property of $\Ext V$ we get an inverse for $\pi'$,
making $\Alt V$ and $\Ext V$ isomorphic as algebras.

We note for later that this $\pi'$ satisfies
$$
(\pi')^{-1}(v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k) = \alt(v_1\tensor\dotsb\tensor v_k).
$$
There are many, many other ways of identifying $\Alt V$ with $\Ext V$;
indeed, if $(X, Y) \mapsto a_{pq}\alt_0(X\tensor Y)$
for $X \in \Alt^pV$ and $Y \in \Alt^qV$
then any coefficients $a_{pq}$ satisfying
$$
a_{p(q+r)}a_{qr}(q+r)! = a_{pq}a_{(p+q)r}(p+q)!
$$
will define an associative product on $\Alt V$
and give an isomorphism with $\Ext V$.
However, the product $(X, Y) \mapsto \alt(X\tensor Y)$
which has $a_{pq} = 1/(p+q)!$
is the only one which is compatible with the natural projection $\pi$
and which gives an $\alt$-map that is a projection.

The issue is the following diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
(\Ext V)^* @>\varphi>> \Ext V^*
\\
@V{\pi^*}VV @VV?V
\\
(\Tensor V)^* @>\psi>> \Tensor V^*
\end{CD}$$
$\varphi$ and $\psi$ are linear isomorphisms,
meaning that for the diagram to commute the arrow $?$
is necessarily $\psi\circ\theta\circ\varphi^{-1}$.
The arrow $\pi^*$ is the dual of $\pi$.
Concretely, it is simply the map that acknowledges
that an alternating multilinear form is a multilinear form.
The map $\psi$ is given by the natural pairing
$\Tensor V^*\times\Tensor V \to \K$
defined by
$$
(\omega_1\tensor\dotsb\tensor\omega_k,\;
 v_1\tensor\dotsb\tensor v_l)
\mapsto \delta_{kl}\omega_1(v_1)\dotsb\omega_k(v_k).
$$
The tricky part is the map $\varphi$.
Like the tensor algebra,
we may define this isomorphism by finding a perfect pairing
$\form{{-},{-}}: \Ext V^*\times\Ext V \to \K$.
There are a variety of ways to derive such a pairing, all of which agree:

Construct the interior product $\lintr : \Ext V^*\times\Ext V \to \Ext V$.
First construct the interior product $V^*\times\Ext V \to \Ext V$,
then use the universal property of $\Ext V^*$
on the resulting map $V^* \to \mathrm{End}(\Ext V)^{\mathrm{opp}}$.
Then $\form{\Omega, Y} = \form{\Omega\lintr Y}_0$
where $\form{-}_0$ is the projection onto $\K = \ExtPow0V$.
(See Multilinear Algebra by Werner Greub.)
$V^*\oplus V$ has a natural symmetric bilinear form,
which gives a Clifford algebra which
canonically contains $\Ext V^*$ and $\Ext V$.
If $\tr X$ is the trace of Clifford multiplication by $X$, then
$\form{\Omega, Y} = \frac1{2^{\dim V}}\tr(\tilde\Omega Y)$
where $\tilde\Omega$ is reversal
$$
    \omega_1\wedge\omega_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge\omega_k
    \mapsto \omega_k\wedge\omega_{k-1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge\omega_1
$$
and $\tilde\Omega Y$ is the Clifford product.
The factor of $2^{\dim V}$ is to normalize the trace,
since $\tr(1) = 2^{\dim V}$
(which is the dimension of the Clifford algebra).
This way constructs $\varphi$ instead of a pairing.
$\Ext V$ has a natural coalgebra structure,
in particular a natural comultiplication map
$\mu' : \Ext V \to \Ext V\otimes\Ext V$.
If $\mu : \K\otimes\K \to \K$ is the field multiplication map
then for any $\alpha, \beta \in (\Ext V)^*$ we define a multiplication
$$
    (\alpha, \beta)
    \mapsto \mu\circ(\alpha\mathbin{\hat\otimes}\beta)\circ\mu'
$$
with $\hat\otimes$ the graded tensor product.
Then, we can embed $\omega \in V^*$ as $\omega' \in (\Ext V)^*$ by defining
$$
    \omega'(X) = \begin{cases}
        \omega(X) &\text{if }X \in V, \\
        0         &\text{if }X \in \ExtPow kV\text{ with }k \ne 1
    \end{cases}
$$
and extending by linearity.
This lets us build up elements of $(\Ext V)^*$
by multiplying together elements of $V^*$,
and in this way we define $\varphi$.
(See Quadratic Mappings and Clifford Algebras
by Artibano Micali and Jacques Helmstetter.)

From any of these definitions, we can compute
$$
\form{\omega_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\omega_k,\;
      v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_l}
= \delta_{kl}\det\bigl(\omega_i(v_j)\bigr)_{i,j=1}^k.
$$
If $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ is a basis for $V$
and $e^1,\dotsc,e^n\in V^*$ its dual, then
$$
\{e_{i_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_{i_k} \;:\; 1\leq i_1<\dotsb<i_k\leq n\}
$$
and the corresponding set for $e^1,\dotsc,e^n$
are bases for $\ExtPow kV$ and $\ExtPow kV^*$.
We can compute that these bases are dual to each other under the above pairing:
$$
\form{e^{i_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge e^{i_k},\;
      e_{j_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_{j_k}}
= \delta^{i_1}_{j_1}\dotsb\delta^{i_k}_{j_k}
$$
with $1 \leq i_1<\dotsb< i_k\leq n$
and $1 \leq j_1<\dotsb< j_k\leq n$.
Now we compute $\psi\circ\pi^*\circ\varphi$ on $\Omega \in \ExtPow kV^*$
and find
$$\begin{aligned}
\psi(\pi^*(\varphi(\Omega)))
  & = \psi\bigl(\pi^*\bigl(\form{\Omega, {-}}\bigr)\bigr)
= \psi\bigl(\form{\Omega, \pi({-})}\bigr)
\\& = \sum_{i_1,\dotsc,i_k = 1}^n
    \form{\Omega,
          \pi(e_{i_1}\tensor\dotsb\tensor e_{i_k})}
    e^{i_1}\tensor\dotsb\tensor e^{i_k}
\\& = \sum_{i_1,\dotsc,i_k = 1}^n
    \form{\Omega,
          e_{i_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_{i_k}}
    e^{i_1}\tensor\dotsb\tensor e^{i_k}
\\& = \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \dotsb < i_k\leq n}
  \form{\Omega,
        e_{i_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_{i_k}}
  \alt_0(e^{i_1}\tensor\dotsb\tensor e^{i_k}).
\end{aligned}$$
Hence
$$
(\psi\circ\pi^*\circ\varphi)(e^{i_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge e^{i_k})
= \alt_0(e^{i_1}\tensor\dotsb\tensor e^{i_k})
$$
but $\omega_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\omega_k = 0$
iff those covectors are linearly dependent,
and any linearly independent $\omega_1,\dotsc,\omega_k$
can be extended to a basis; it follows that
$$
(\psi\circ\pi^*\circ\varphi)(\omega_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\omega_k)
= \alt_0(\omega_1\tensor\dotsb\tensor\omega_k)
$$
for all $\omega_1,\dotsc,\omega_k \in V^*$.
Contrast this with the identity for $\pi'$, which I repeat here:
$$
(\pi')^{-1}(v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k) = \alt(v_1\tensor\dotsb\tensor v_k).
$$
We're missing some factorials in $\psi\circ\pi^*\circ\varphi$!
Indeed, let $\Omega \in \TensorPow pV^*$, $\Theta \in \TensorPow qV^*$,
$X \in \TensorPow pV$, and $Y \in \TensorPow qV$.
The $\psi\circ\pi^*\circ\varphi$ product may be written
$$
(\Omega, \Theta)
\mapsto \frac1{p!q!}\alt_0(\Omega\tensor\Theta)
= \frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}\alt(\Omega\tensor\Theta)
$$
whereas the $\pi'$ product is written
$$
(X, Y) \mapsto \frac1{(p+q)!}\alt_0(X\tensor Y) = \alt(X\tensor Y).
$$

In terms of the expressions in your question, this means that we should have
$$
  u\wedge v = \frac12(u\tensor v - v\tensor u)
$$
but
$$
  dx^i\wedge dx^j = dx^i\tensor dx^j - dx^j\tensor dx^i
$$
and so
$$
  (dx^i\wedge dx^j)(u\wedge v)
  = (dx^i\tensor dx^j - dx^j\tensor dx^i)(u\tensor v - v\tensor u)/2
  = dx^i(u)dx^j(v) - dx^i(v)dx^j(u).
$$

Very nice explanation but this is why I avoid ever taking wedge products of tangent vectors.
